# How to view documentation for an installed library?

Tags: shared-library, documentation

I installed `doxygen` and `doxygen-doc`. The man page for doxygen tells me to get doxygen-doc for more information. 
I found the `doxygen-doc` in my `usr/share/doc`, but its a compressed archive. So how can I access it conveniently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't state the version of Ubuntu you use, but for Trusty, there's a PDF manual in `/usr/share/doc/doxygen/doxygen_manual.pdf`.

There's also HTML documentation here: `/usr/share/doc/doxygen/html/index.html`

I can't spot a compressed archive besides the changelog (`/usr/share/doc/doxygen-doc/changelog.Debian.gz`) that you'd look at using `zless`.

Comment: So after `sudo apt-get install doxygen-doc` it actually puts the documentation not into `/usr/share/doc/doxygen-doc/` but into `/usr/share/doc/doxygen/`? **EDIT**: Yes it sure looks this way, so I guess I better get used to this fast :)

Answer (score 3):

## Finding Documentation on ubuntu

### 1. Search using nautilus or browser

You can search as mentioned above in the **/usr/share/doc** directory, but some packages install it in their **/usr/share/package_name** directories or even other locations. Here you can find the **html** and **pdf** docus, best using **nautilus** (use the search function of nautilus and open your requested docu in your **browser**). If you often use the docu don't forget to bookmark your link.

### 2. Using find command

From your command line you can use the **find** command to search for  your docu:

- html-documentation:

  `find /usr/share -type f -name index.html | grep doxy`
- pdf-documention:

  `find /usr/share/ -type f -name *.pdf | grep doxy`

Invoke your result with evince or your browser (in my case google-chrome)

- html:

  `google-chrome /usr/share/doc/doxygen/html/index.html`
- pdf:

  `google-chrome /usr/share/doc/doxygen_manual.pdf`

  `evince /usr/share/doc/doxygen_manual.pdf`

### 3. Make a list and search and invoke with less

I prefer to automate this task and make a list the following way:

- for html:

  `find /usr/share/ -type f -name index.html | sort -k1 | awk '{ print "file://" $0;}' > ~/DocHtml.txt`
- for pdf:

  `find /usr/share/ -type f -name *.pdf | sort -k1 | awk '{ print "file://" $0;}' > ~/DocPdf.txt`

This will create 2 files in your home-directory (*DocPdf.txt* and *DocHtml.txt*). Simply open this with **less**

```
less ~/DocPdf.txt
```

or

```
less ~/DocHtml.txt
```

and press <kbd>&</kbd> followed with your searching string, e.g. doxygen. 
Now simple move your mouse over the requested document and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and **left-mouse-click** will open the file.

You can also make a bash script and invoke it via a chron job. This will automate the task.

Here is a simple bash script which can be modified. Put additional directories as desscribed in the script. Save the below bash script as **makeDoc**, change **chmod +x makeDoc** and invoke it with **./makeDoc**. Rest as above:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author: abu
# Description: script creates two files, DocPdf.txt and DocHtml.txt, 
#   which lists all pdf/html documents found by the find function.
#
#   You can include other search directories, e.g. Anaconda, 

declare -a DocDirs=(
    "/usr/share/"
    "/opt/anaconda3/"       # you can put here additional  directories
#   "/path/to/other/dirs/"  # -""-     -""-    -""-
)

echo "DocHtml automatic generated!" > DocHtml.txt
echo "   File generated with" $0 >> DocHtml.txt
echo -e "   Date: " `date` "\n\n" >> DocHtml.txt

echo "DocPdf automatic generated!" > DocPdf.txt
echo "   File generated with" $0 >> DocPdf.txt
echo -e "   Date: " `date` "\n\n" >> DocPdf.txt

for i in "${DocDirs[@]}"
do
    find $i -type f -name index.html | sort -k1 | awk '{ print "file://" $0;}' >> ~/DocHtml.txt
    find $i -type f -name *.pdf | sort -k1 | awk '{ print "file://" $0;}' >> ~/DocPdf.txt
done
```

### 4. APT Package Solution

The package **doc-base** helps developers to install it in the correct way. To view this I know **dhelp** and **doc-central**.

**4.1 dhelp**: web base documentation reader.

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install dhelp
```

and open in your browser the file:

```
file:///usr/share/doc/HTML/Programming/Awk/index.html
```

- documentation are well indexed
- documentation is available through a web browser
- indexes documentation (in the background)
- not so convenient command line interface
  .

**4.2 doc-central**: web base documentation reader.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install doc-central
```

- documentation are well indexed
- documentation is available through a web browser
- indexes documentation (in the background)
- not so convenient command line interface